# How to move li elements from one list to another

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listview

Here i am moving the whole li elements from one list to another list.What i need is to select a particular li element from one list and on button click it has to move to another list.
Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        $("#list1 li").appendTo('#list2');
    });
});
```

and

```
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul id="list1" class="connectedSortable">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>    
            <li class="ui-state-default" ><%# Eval("value") %></li>     
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

    <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul id="list2" class="connectedSortable">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>    
            <li class="ui-state-highlight" ><%# Eval("value2") %></li>     
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <input id="add" name="add" type="button" value="add" /><br />
</div>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: so what is the problem with this code ? are you getting any error. and it is better to provide the HTML markup as its going to be jQuery question

Comment: Any chance you could just add the plain html not the server code, and possibly an example on jsfiddle.net. Cheers.

Comment: i need to move a single li element from list1 to list2 on a button click..that is my problem

Comment: Ahh - I see, the jQuery posted copies ALL items, you want a specific item.

Comment: The crucial bit of info here I think is how you *select* something which is a listitem - e.g. a string, a label - it's not a dropdownlist, therefore you have no access to the ":selected" pseudo selector, so I don't quite understand what you expect? There is a complete disconnect between the button click and the collection of LIs

Comment: ya i have tried like this also it is not working $("#list1 option:selected").appendTo("#list2");

Comment: ok then it is not possible is it?

Comment: How do you specifiy which item you want to select? Who is the "one" that you want to move to the other list?

Comment: but i can able to do drag from a particular li element from one list and drop in another list using this piece of code $(function () {
            $("#list1, #list2").sortable({
             connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
         }).disableSelection();
     });

Comment: by dragging, or clicking (using the examples below from Dave, etc) - you're clicking the listitem. your sample code shows a button click required to do the move, which is a different animal altogether.

Comment: ya ok thanks  SpaceBison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        $("#list1 li").last().appendTo('#list2');
    });
});
```

EDIT: To move a specific item:

```
$("#list1 li").click(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#list2');
});
```

ADDITIONAL EDIT: To make a list item clickable, and then append that item when the Add button is clicked (not tested).

```
$("#list1 li").click(function() {
    $("list1 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked");
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
});
$("#add").click(function () {
    $("#list1 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list2');
});
```

Comment: but i can able to do drag from a particular li element from one list and drop in another list using this piece of code $(function () { $("#list1, #list2").sortable({ connectWith: ".connectedSortable" }).disableSelection(); });

Comment: how come i can able to select a particular li element by using that piece of code

Comment: Drag and drop is a more complicated thing, but there should be plenty of jQuery plugins out there you can google.

Comment: but even that complicated drag and drop is working fine for me

Comment: It works because YOU make the choice of WHICH item to move - using the example with the button, there's no click on the listitem - this is the crucial difference.

Comment: in a double click i have to move a li item from one list to another list

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jKvZB/2/

```
list 1:
<ul id="list1">
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>world</li>
</ul>
<br />
list 2:
<ul id="list2">
    <li>goodbye</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" id="listSwap">go</a>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#listSwap").click(function() {
        $("#list1 li:nth-child(2)").hide();
        $("#list2").append("<li>"+$("#list1 li:nth-child(2)").html()+"</li>");
    });
});
```

It's pretty basic, but I'm sure you can work it out from there.

Answer (score 1):

if you just move a sing li element,you should have a unique attribute for each li element and then use jquery selector function to select one and append to other element.

this may be can help you :

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li class="ui-state-default 01"> list1-1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default 02"> list1-2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default 03"> list1-3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list2"></ul>

    $("#list1 .01").appendTo($("#list2"));
    or 
    $("#list1 li:last").appendTo($("#list2"));
```

similar to the Dave's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".add").click(function () {
            $(this).appendTo('#list2');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will make it so whichever specific li element is clicked is the one that will be moved over. Just make sure the li's have the class "add"